# Symfony2/Doctrine2 ManyToMany DQL "has no association named" error

Tags: orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to make a DQL query, which keeps giving me this error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 68 near 'r': Error: Class Custom\SystemBundle\Entity\Element has no association named CustomAuthBundle:Role
```

The code for these Entities look like this:

Role:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Custom\SystemBundle\Entity\Element", mappedBy="role_id")
 */
 private $element_id;
```

Element:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Custom\AuthBundle\Entity\Role", inversedBy="element_id")
 */
private $role_id;
```

And here is the query:

```
php app/console doctrine:query:dql 'SELECT e FROM CustomSystemBundle:Element e JOIN e.CustomAuthBundle:Role r'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You define your *object* model, so there's no place for `role_id` or `element_id`. Objects will be stored there, not their identifiers. So `abc_id` → `abc`.
2. Assocations are defined by *properties*, not classnames:

   ```
   […] JOIN e.role r […]
   ```

Comment: Yeah, I just got that a minute ago. Thank you for your answer!